# React relay tutorial undefined error

Tags: javascript, relayjs

Why does:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

show after completing and subsequently testing the tutorial?

Comment: To make it easier to diagnose your problem, copy what you've written into the Relay Playground and post a link to it here. https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser probably doesn't have the polyfill it needs:

Add the repeat polyfill into your app.js before the render call.
From MDN:

```
if (!String.prototype.repeat) {
  String.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
    'use strict';
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('can\'t convert ' + this + ' to object');
    }
    var str = '' + this;
    count = +count;
    if (count != count) {
      count = 0;
    }
    if (count < 0) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be non-negative');
    }
    if (count == Infinity) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be less than infinity');
    }
    count = Math.floor(count);
    if (str.length == 0 || count == 0) {
      return '';
    }
    // Ensuring count is a 31-bit integer allows us to heavily optimize the
    // main part. But anyway, most current (August 2014) browsers can't handle
    // strings 1 << 28 chars or longer, so:
    if (str.length * count >= 1 << 28) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must not overflow maximum string size');
    }
    var rpt = '';
    for (;;) {
      if ((count & 1) == 1) {
        rpt += str;
      }
      count >>>= 1;
      if (count == 0) {
        break;
      }
      str += str;
    }
    return rpt;
  }
}
```